# No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Uri'

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this model:

```
public class Something
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Uri Hyperlink { get; set; }
}
```

All `Uri` types are persisted in database as as string using fluent api using the following code:

```
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Uri))
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name).Property<Uri>(property.Name).HasConversion(
    x => x.ToString(),
    x => new Uri(x));
}
```

But when running `databaseContext.Database.EnsureCreated();`, I receive the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Uri'. The following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity: 'uriString', 'uriString', 'dontEscape', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'dontEscape', 'uriString', 'uriKind', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'serializationInfo', 'streamingContext', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'flags', 'uriParser', 'uri'.'

Answer (score 0):

Try treat the property as a string and add annotation like this

```
public class Something
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string Hyperlink { get; set; }
}
```

OR this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Something>().Property(p => p.Hyperlink)
            .HasConversion(
                p => p.Value,
                p => Hyperlink.FromValue(p));
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after adding `[DataType(DataType.Url)]`

Comment: @Yann answer updated, try the second option and inform me please

Comment: Using string (as opposed to Uri type) works as a workaround, and is what I have resorted to doing for now. The "Hyperlink.FromValue" solution itself did not work as Hyperlink does not exist in the current context.

And, while using `string` as the workaround technically works, unfortunately it isn't an answer in storing Uri type via EF core as it requires to either abandon the Uri type or perform value conversion outside of EF Core...